# (C++) Problems with saving vector into .txt database

Tags: c++, file, vector

So I have a .txt database where I store player data. Each line represents a new player. For example, if I create 2 players, the file should look like this.

```
PlayerID 0|Name|Biography|0|0|0|0|0|0
PlayerID 1|Name|Biography|0|0|0|0|0|0
```

I have 2 problems. First, I am not sure if my character creation function is working. There is a function which loops the character vector and modifies the IDs consecutively (1, 2, 3, etc.). Here is the function:

```
int newID = 0;

Character newCharacter(name, biography, 1, 0, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, newID);
characterVec.push_back(newCharacter);

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < characterVec.size(); i++)
{
    characterVec[i].id = i;
    activeCharacter = i;
}
```

Second problem is character saving. I am sure I haven't made it right. The loop is supposed to write the whole character vector into the .txt database, then somehow save it (i used flush()). Here is the code:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < characterVec.size(); i++)
{
    characterDatabase << characterVec[i].id << "|";
    characterDatabase << characterVec[i].name << "|" << characterVec[i].biography << "|";
    characterDatabase << characterVec[i].level << "|" << characterVec[i].xp << "|";
    characterDatabase << characterVec[i].xpMax << "|" << characterVec[i].hp << "|";
    characterDatabase << characterVec[i].hpMax << "|" << characterVec[i].orbs << "|";
    characterDatabase << characterVec[i].diamonds << endl;
}

characterDatabase.flush();
```

I also have a code that loads the file into the vector, but it's really big so I might paste it on a website then send the link. However, I think it doesn't have to do anything with my problem.

### The question is, how can I fix player saving? And is anything wrong with the player creation function?

When I run the program, everything works fine, but after I save the progress and restart it, nothing will load. However, if I manually add a player in the .txt database, run the program and print the characters list, the player will load and be displayed. So there is a problem in my auto saving/loading code, since it works manually.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with either function. What actually happens when you run the code? It's not helpful to just say 'it doesn't work'. What does the output file look like (assuming you have one).

Comment: `flush()` is unnecessary BTW

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say the problem is in the code around the two snippetts of code you've posted. Are you opening the file correctly, are you passing the vector from the creation code to the writing code correctly? etc. etc.

Comment: I edited the question to explain what happens if i run the program.

Comment: `The player will load and be displayed` Just the player you've manually added, or all players will now load and dispay?

Comment: Just the manually added players (the players I added myself in the text file) not the ones I created in the program.

Comment: Off the top of my head it seems far more likely that the problem is in the loading code (which is the more complex task anyway). In any case I doubt the problem is in the code you've posted so far which looks fine.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/eyojiqugoq.cpp here is the code for character loading

Comment: That looks fine too

Comment: That's strange...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211118/discussion-between-wenor-and-john).

Comment: what you need to do is post a **complete program**. It should not be your current program which is probably far too big. Instead you should start removing code while keeping the behaviour you don't understand. When you got the program as small as possible post it here and your database. This is called a minimal complete verifiable example

Comment: I made another program but still have the exact same problem... manually added objects work but objects added by code don't save in file. Here is the link to it: https://hastebin.com/ogazobucim.cpp

Comment: Your file handling is wrong. Don't declare one global `fstream` object. Declare one `ifstream` object in `loadObjects` and an `ofstream` in `saveObjects`. You can't mix input and output on the same fstream (at least not without knowing what you are doing). The simple way is to use a different fstream object for each operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will update my code tomorrow.

Comment: The .txt database and the IDs are finally working properly! Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

read about filestream, string stream of std and iterators
here is some pseudocode to understand conceptions

```
// pseudo code
class MyCharacterManager {
public:
    void LoadChars() {
      // do ifstream from file to string stream, do iterate of all strings each string to you character data 
      for ( auto it = /* whrite iterator over stringstream to each line get data from there*/ )
        // copy constructor involved here 
        characterVec.push_back(Character( ... ) )
    }

    void SaveChars() {
       stringstream out;
       for ( auto it = characterVec.begin(); it != characterVec.end(); it++ ) {
           string data;
           // print you data to string
           stringstream << string << endl;
       } 
       //  do write with fstream here
    }

private:
 ... characterVec;
}
```